# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/BootstrapMode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing this project with spring boot and I tried to write some tests but sadly I get this exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [somepath/config/PostgresJpaConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/BootstrapMode
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/BootstrapMode
```

I looked if some sort of dependency was missing in my **build.gradle**, but I don't think so. The *BootstrapMode* thingy doesn't exist anywhere, not even on the Central Maven Repository. I searched through my entire project with IntelliJ for any type of *BootstrapMode* appearance, without any luck.

These are my gradle dependencies:
[image: Gradle Dependencies]

This is my PostgrsJpaConfig class:
[PostgresJpaConfig class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPbdQ.png)

Comment: Looks like you are mixing spring versions.

Comment: How so? @M.Deinum

Comment: Because that is a feature in the new Spring Data JPA... So unless you are using Spring Boot 2.1 that shouldn't be available. SO you are probably overriding versions in your `build.gradle` which you shouldn't do. So please add the `build.gradle` to your question.

Comment: Why do you even need the PostgresJpaConfig class?

Comment: @M.Deinum I added the build.gradle

Comment: @BlueScoreMan Could you tell us the value of `${springBootVersion}` which you use in your build.gradle?

Comment: Please don't post code/gradle files as images... Post them as code. Instead of `org.springframework.data` use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Remove the hibernate dependency and also the AssertJ dependency (hibernate is managed by the data jpa starter and AssertJ by the test starter).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli To be able to do my tests I followed this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing . I did everything step by step but it still failed, so I decied to clone to whole GitHub Project https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot , and see what was missing on my part.

Comment: @AhmedBajra The version would be _2.0.2.RELEASE_

Comment: Then, just as @M.Deinum has already said, you're using two different spring versions

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! Atleast I'm getting a new error now :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> TL;DR:  I was mixing up Spring versions. Overriding one version with
>   another, which you shouldn't do.

Instead of using the `org.springframework.data` dependency, I should use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.